# How can I create a QuickSort implementation in Swift?

Tags: swift, sorting, quicksort

I'm learning swift and I've implemented varius sorting algorithms as ADT to practise. I'm just struggeling with quick sort which somehow won't work. Could someone tell me where the flaw in the code is?

```
func quickSort(start: Int, end: Int) {
    if (end <= start) { return }
    let pivot = self.srtdArr[end]
    var left = start
    var right = end - 1
    while left < right {
        while ((self.srtdArr[left] <= pivot) && (left < end)) {
            left += 1
        }
        while ((self.srtdArr[right] >= pivot) && (right > start)) {
            right -= 1
        }
        if left < right { self.srtdArr.swapAt(left, right) }
    }
    self.srtdArr.swapAt(left, end)
    quickSort(start: start, end: right)
    quickSort(start: right+1, end: end)
    return
}
```

Honestly I've varied the code to often to wrap my head around the problem properly anymore that's why I need fresh input. Whilst debugging I first noticed that sometimes the code got itself into a recursive loop. I changed some iterator or Boolean operator and now it determines, but not quit correctly and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you start with a java algorithm and just convert it to Swift https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort

[image]

The Swift version should look something like this:

```
func quickSort(_ arr: inout [Int], begin: Int, end: Int) {
    if begin < end {
        let partitionIndex = partition(&arr, begin: begin, end: end)
        quickSort(&arr, begin: begin, end: partitionIndex - 1)
        quickSort(&arr, begin: partitionIndex + 1, end: end)
    }
}
func partition(_ arr: inout [Int], begin: Int, end: Int) -> Int {
    let pivot = arr[end]
    var i = begin - 1
    for j in begin..<end {
        if arr[j] <= pivot {
            i += 1
            arr.swapAt(i, j)
        }
    }
    arr.swapAt(i + 1, end)
    return i + 1
}
```

---

If you would like to make quickSort a mutable generic method on collection to be used with any Comparable Element:

```
extension MutableCollection where Self: RandomAccessCollection, Element: Comparable, Index == Int {
    mutating func quickSort(begin: Int, end: Int) {
        if begin < end {
            let partitionIndex = partition(begin: begin, end: end)
            quickSort(begin: begin, end: partitionIndex - 1)
            quickSort(begin: partitionIndex + 1, end: end)
        }
    }
    mutating func partition(begin: Int, end: Int) -> Int {
        let pivot = self[end]
        var i = begin - 1
        for j in begin..<end where self[j] <= pivot {
            i += 1
            swapAt(i, j)
        }
        swapAt(i + 1, end)
        return i + 1
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
var array = [1,3,2,5,4,7,6]
array.quickSort(begin: 0, end: 6)
array  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive calls are incorrect

After your loop finishes, you swap pivot with `left`:
`self.srtdArr.swapAt(left, end)`
so your pivot is located at position `left` after the loop

This means that now you need to sort arrays `[start, left-1]` and `[left+1, end]`:

```
quickSort(start: start, end: left-1)
quickSort(start: left+1, end: end)
```